# SharePoint Development on Windows 7

Tags: sharepoint, windows-7

I am about to install SharePoint Foundation for development purposes on my Windows 7 x64.
I will be using Visual Studio 2010.

Beside other things, MS site says:
*If you use Windows 7 or Windows Vista for your development environment, you should have access to a test environment that has the same operating system installed as your production environment.*

I am not sure what does it exactly mean by "you should have access to test environment"? 
Will I be able to compile, run debug and test web parts and other stuff?
Are there any significant limitations for Win 7 and SP Foundation for development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SharePoint production OS should be win2008+ by saying "the same operating system" they mean win2008+, neither win7 or Vista should be used as testing servers. This passage means that there should be another server that will be win 2008 and will host SharePoint and this server should be the one you should test your solutions on.

p.s. yes. there are some low level differences between sharepoint hosted on win7 and win 2088. but you will be able to do all the stuff you want on win 7 too.